# Is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

My first thought was that there should exist a list of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Namely because, given a finite sequence, we can find all possible orderings of the sequence. However, $\mathbb{N}$ is not finite, leading me to believe that I can't list all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: Notice that even the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$ is uncountable, which can be easily proved by adopting Cantor's diagonal argument. Of course, this argument can be directly applied to the set of all function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set  $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and is not countable. $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a subset of the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it supposes the OP knows, or understands, that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not countable. Given the implicit background in the question, I would not think this is the case..

Comment: The proof that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable should go as follows: Let $E$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$. Suppose $E$ is countable, and arrive at a contradiction. Right?

Comment: It is a general result that a the cardinal of a set is strictly inferior to the cardinal of its power set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#General_sets

Comment: 1. More specifically about how to use "Cantor's diagonal argument": This is similar to exercise 2.5-38 in Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen. The answer by the book has "Hint: First set up a *one-to-one correspondence* between
the set of real numbers between 0 and 1 and a subset of
these functions. Do this by associating to the real number
$0.d_1d_2 … d_n …$ the function f with $f(n) = d_n$". It then concludes the set of the *total* function is countable and then the set of all functions including both total and *partial* functions is also countable.

Comment: Then we follow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Real_numbers which constructs "a bijection from (0, 1) to R" in the proof process.
2. Rushabh Mehta's answer complements Tsemo Aristide's comments where $\phi$ maps $f$ to the subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the set of functions from $\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$ has the same cardinality as the powerset of $\mathbb N$, since we can create a bijection as follows:

$$\phi: \{\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}\} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$$$$f\mapsto \{x\in\mathbb N\;|\;f(x)=1\}$$

The powerset has larger cardinality than the naturals by Cantor's Diagonal Argument.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can easily adopt Cantor's diagonal argument to this question:

Each $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ can be written as a series $f(1), f(2),...$.

If the set of such functions was countable you can order it, and draw up a chart to include all such series. Try using Cantor's diagonal argument now to construct a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to arrive at a contradiction.